# How to exclude context path from CSF service path?

Tags: java, soap

I am using cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws with Spring Boot for SOAP Services.
The web application has the URL http://localhost:8080/abc/def/.
The WSDL must be located at http://localhost:8080/service?wsdl.

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/abc/def
cxf.path=/
```

Endpoint registration in Application.java:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint(MySoapService service) {
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(service);
    endpoint.publish("/service");
    return endpoint;
}
```

As a result, WSDL URL includes server.servlet.context-path and looks like http://localhost:8080/abc/def/service?wsdl. I could not find a solution, to get the path to the service from the root. Is there a way to solve the issue?